# The DateTime control is returning an exception during data binding

Tags: java, datetime, swt, eclipse-rcp

I am using Eclipse DataBinding and I am trying to bind the SWT DateTime control and then but when I tried to set a value for DateTime it returns an exception.

Here's my stacktrace

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot set null selection on DateTime
at org.eclipse.jface.internal.databinding.swt.DateTimeSelectionProperty.doSetValue(DateTimeSelectionProperty.java:70)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.property.value.ValueProperty.setValue(ValueProperty.java:89)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.databinding.property.value.SimplePropertyObservableValue.doSetValue(SimplePropertyObservableValue.java:110)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.value.AbstractObservableValue.setValue(AbstractObservableValue.java:66)
```

Here's my code to prepare the binding, the dateTimeNode is the ObservableValue

```
DataBindingContext ctx = new DataBindingContext();
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime( composite, SWT.DATE | SWT.MEDIUM | SWT.DROP_DOWN | SWT.BORDER );
IObservableValue<?> widgetValue = WidgetProperties.selection().observe( dateTime );
ctx.bindValue( widgetValue, dateTimeNode );
```

and then I added the control to my tree by using the TreeEditor

```
new TreeEditor().setEditor( dateTime, getTime( dateTimeNode ), 1 );
```

Comment: what is `composite` in `new DateTime( composite...` ?

Comment: @ScaryWombat the composite is my tree, and I used the getTree() to get it from TreeViewer

Comment: Check that it is not null